# Перевод сообщений валидации

Tags: asp.net-core

Создаю сайт на Asp.Net Core, в нем имеется регистрация и форма обратной связи.
В формах установлена валидация (заполнено или нет поле, кол-во символов и др.).

С формой проблем нет, все работает прекрасно, но вот незадача - сообщения валидации выдаются на английском языке.

Помогите, как перевести данные сообщения?

[Как реализована валидация](http://dotnet.today/ru/aspnet5-vnext/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation.html)

Картинка того, что нудно перевести (красный текст):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допишите в [атрибуты валидации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) Вашей модели текст ошибки ErrorMessage = "Моя ошибка" (для отображения только на русском языке).

Либо используйте ресурсы ([ErrorMessageResourceName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)) для многоязычного сайта

Comment: Фига вы господа, вспомнили... Спустя ~5 месяцев пошли ответы. Мдяя, посмешили. Ну а сам ответ, именно Ваш, вполне годный, в итоге так и поступил. Только ссылку на `ErrorMessageResourceName` поправить бы не помешало.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ эта "фига"  может помочь другим, кто начнет искать такую проблему ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Вытяжка из книги "ASP.NET Core разработка приложений"

Аннотации данных 
В кодовой базе осталось еще одно последнее место, которое может содержать лока- 
лизуемый текст. Аннотации данных, используемые в классах моделей представле- 
ний, позже используются тег-хелперами в Razor для отображения соответствую- 
щих меток и сообщений об ошибках проверки. Рассмотрим класс LoginViewModel, 
используемый в представлении Account/Login. 
Класс LoginViewModel, используемый в Account/Login

```
public class LoginViewModel 
{ 
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")] 
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Not a valid email address")] 
[Display(Name= "Email")] 
public string Email { get; set; } 
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")] 
[DataType(DataType.Password)] 
[Display(Name="Password")] 
public string Password { get; set; } 
[Display(Name = "Remember me?")] 
public bool RememberMe { get; set; } 
}
```

Локализованные версии сообщений об ошибках аннотаций данных загружа- 
ются во время выполнения из файлов ресурсов с использованием соглашений 
об именах, сходных с теми, которые использует IStringLocalizer. Текст для ка- 
надского французского может загружаться из файла ресурсов Resources/Models. 
AccountViewModels.LoginViewModel.fr-CA.resx. 
Учтите, что на момент написания книги значения Name, указанные в атрибуте 
Display, не локализуются. Локализация отображаемых имен будет поддерживать- 
ся в ASP.NET Core MVC 1.1 при выпуске.

Answer (score -1):

В представлении просто найдите эти валивации и замените английские сообщения на русские. Если делали через шаблон в английской студии не забудьте проверить кодировку файла, так как в английской версии utf8 идёт без BOM. Да, это подходит если сам пишешь валидацию, а тут нужно в атрибуте прописать ошибку на русском

Comment: В данном примеру валидация основана на DataAnnotations, следовательно надо применять собственные описания ошибок, на нужном языке.